# LinkedIn JavaScript API not working on HTTPS

Tags: jquery, asp.net, linkedin-jsapi

Till now I have used `LinkedIn JavaScript API` for one of site (Sign in using Linked In) which was on `http` and it was working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: XXXXXXXXXXX
    scope: r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_contactinfo r_network
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInAuth() {
        IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields("id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress")

.result(function (me) {
    var member = me.values[0];
});
</script>
```

Body:

```
<script type="in/Login" data-onauth="onLinkedInAuth">
    Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
</script>
```

But now, I have moved site to `(https)` and suddenly it has stopped working and browser keep blocking the unsecured content so we could not see the `sign in using linked in` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `http` with `https` in the script source.

For example:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: XXX
    scope: XXX
</script>
```